# Failing to train SkipGram word embedding in Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I am training the skipgram word embeddings using the famous model described in https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4546. I want to train it in PyTorch but I am getting errors and I can't figure out where they are coming from. Below I have provided my model class, training loop, and batching method. Does anyone have any insight into whats going on?

I am getting an error on the `output = loss(data, target)` line. It is having a problem with `<class 'torch.LongTensor'>` which is weird because CrossEntropyLoss takes a long tensor. The output shape might be wrong which is: `torch.Size([1000, 100, 1000])` after the feedforward.

I have my model defined as:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.manual_seed(1)

class SkipGram(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim):
        super(SkipGram, self).__init__()
        self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.hidden_layer = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, vocab_size)

        # Loss needs to be input: (minibatch (N), C) target: (minibatch, 1), each label is a class
        # Calculate loss in training            

    def forward(self, x):
        embeds = self.embeddings(x)
        x = self.hidden_layer(embeds)
        return x
```

My training is defined as:

```
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable

net = SkipGram(1000, 300)
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)

batch_size = 100
size = len(train_ints)

batches = batch_index_gen(batch_size, size)
inputs, targets = build_tensor_from_batch_index(batches[0], train_ints)


for i in range(100):
    running_loss = 0.0

    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(batches):
        data, target = build_tensor_from_batch_index(batch, train_ints)
#         if (torch.cuda.is_available()):
#             data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()
#             net = net.cuda()
        data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = net.forward(data)
        loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()    
        output = loss(data, target)
        output.backward()
        optimizer.step()                        
        running_loss += loss.data[0]
        optimizer.step()

        print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                i, batch_idx * len(batch_size), len(size),
                100. * (batch_idx * len(batch_size)) / len(size), loss.data[0]))
```

If useful my batching is:

```
def build_tensor_from_batch_index(index, train_ints):
    minibatch = []
    for i in range(index[0], index[1]):
        input_arr = np.zeros( (1000,1), dtype=np.int )
        target_arr = np.zeros( (1000,1), dtype=np.int )
        input_index, target_index = train_ints[i]
        input_arr[input_index] = 1
        target_arr[input_index] = 1

        input_tensor = torch.from_numpy(input_arr)
        target_tensor = torch.from_numpy(target_arr)

        minibatch.append( (input_tensor, target_tensor) )

    # Concatenate all tensors into a minibatch
    #x = [tensor[0] for tensor in minibatch]
    #print(x)
    input_minibatch = torch.cat([tensor[0] for tensor in minibatch], 1)
    target_minibatch = torch.cat([tensor[1] for tensor in minibatch], 1)

    #target_minibatch = minibatch[0][1]
    return input_minibatch, target_minibatch
```

Comment: Just a couple of hints: Don't call optimizer.step() twice. You don't need to define your loss function each time, just do it outside of the training loop. You defined `loss` as a function, so this `running_loss += loss.data[0]` will throw an error. Also I think you do not want to  sum up the loss on each epoch. An average over the batch will be calculated by default by the CrossEntropyLoss function. Have a look at DataLoader of PyTorch. It provides an easy wrapper for parallel loading and batching of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that since I did not read the paper, but seems weird that you are computing the loss with the original data and the targets:

```
output = loss(data, target)
```

Considering that the output of the network is `output = net.forward(data)` I think you should compute your loss as:

```
error = loss(output, target)
```

If this doesn't help, briefly point me out what the paper says about the loss function.